# Find an elegant single regex for JavaScript regexp multiples of inner pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's the match text:

`bla bla bla <!--[mixed token 1][mixed token 2][...]-->`

I want just the tokens in the text.match(/.../) array.

I can solve this by matching out everything w/in the comments first and then running a second pattern on `[mixed token 1][mixed token 2]` but everything else I've tried doesn't give a clean result.

Something like this was working great for a text with a single token pattern in it but falls short solving the above.
`/<!--\[(.*?)\]-->/`

The next best I came up with always wanted to return "`mixed token 1][mixed token 2`"

@note that the goal is to not limit the number of [token] sets that can exist w/in the comment bookends

[regexr](http://regexr.com/3cbkc) started based on jcaron's work below

Comment: can you provide what you tried?

Comment: What have you got now? @Grundy jinx!

Comment: and what expected result for you sample?

Comment: Honestly don't think you're going to be able to do this without look behinds (.js doesn't support them). You could use `(?:\[(.*?)\])`, but that won't account for it being inside `<!-- -->`

Comment: With no limit on the number of tokens, I don't think there's any way

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
/<!--(?:\[([^\]]+)\])(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?-->/
```

You can add more optional non-capturing groups to capture more tokens, and of course, you might need to handle spaces and whatnot between or around the tokens.

Example:

```
"bla bla bla <!--[mixed token 1][mixed token 2]-->".match(/<!--(?:\[([^\]]+)\])(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?-->/)
```

Result:

```
["<!--[mixed token 1][mixed token 2]-->", "mixed token 1", "mixed token 2", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

So you get the tokens at positions 1 and following in the array returned.

Obviously, this is not as generic as matching the whole comment and then using another regex match or a split of some kind.

Comment: which is cool and I thought about, but there would still need to be post processing to get just the token out of the bookends

Comment: What exactly is the bit you want to get? Just the `mixed token 1` part without the brackets?

Comment: Edited the answer to get just the `mixed token 1` without the brackets. Not sure any of this qualifies for "elegant", though.